# How do I handle person height within a simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Profile` model, that has a `height` attribute.

I need to store the height of users (aka profiles), but I am not quite sure how to do it. I assume the best way to do it is to have a select dropdown broken down in inches (i.e. 4'0", 4'1"...6'5", etc.). But I am not quite sure the best way to store this in the db.

I would assume it is simplest to just store inches, but if I do how do I present the height in my select in the format I specified above.

Right now, I just have an integer field:

```
<%= f.input_field :height, placeholder: "176", class: 'col-lg-9 form-control' %>
```

Comment: why not you have a cm field and an image to convert inch to cm. Then in the model you can write logic to convert it into inches if necessary

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff I am not sure I understand your suggestion. An "image to convert inch to cm"? What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `number field` for this. When saving the users height or updating a user height you can provide an option for the user either choosing it in `inches or cms`. You can either use `javascript or jquery` to convert to appropriate units before saving or you can use a `before filter` for updating and creating operations.

You can do the following instead of `text_field` and you can even set min and max values for height.

`<%= f.number_field :height, placeholder: "176", class: 'col-lg-9 form-control' %>`

Comment: But how does this give me a select tag that shows the feet options in the dropdown to the user (i.e. 4'0", 4'1", 4'2", etc.) and then convert it to inches upon submission. How do I do that?

Comment: You can create a select tag using java script or using rails you can use the select_tag for this.

Comment: Could you update your answer with some suggestions for what that might look like please? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you set up a select tag so that it displays one piece of information but passes along another piece of information.  So it display 4'0" but passes along 48 - and so forth

Answer (score 1):

1.Change hieght variable data type to float as centimeters.

2.Display drop down of foot and inches and convert it into centimeters before save and viceversa before display stored data.

in your view:

```
<select name=profile[height]>height
<option>4.1</option>
<option>4.2</option>
<option>4.3</option>
<option>4.4</option>
</select>
```

in your create action of controller:

```
@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
@profile.height = @profile.height*30.48 #convert foot to centimeters
@profile.save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create select box with value and option to select.

For example: value in database will be `4.4`, but option in select will be `4'4`

```
 <% arr = (1..10).step(0.1).to_a.map{|k| k.round(1).to_s.sub(".", "'"), [k.round(1) ]  } %>

 <%= f.select :height, arr, placeholder: "176", class: 'col-lg-9 form-control' %>
```

`(1..10)` is your scope ,you can put here range whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code snippet that shows one way that this could look. If you add the inches integer value to the select option tags, you could then grab it using jQuery upon a save operation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save').on('click', function(){
   alert($('#height').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='height'>
  <option value="72">6'0"</option>
  <option value="73">6'1"</option>
  <option value="74">6'2"</option>
  <option value="75">6'3"</option>
  <option value="76">6'4"</option>     
</select>
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
```